# Function gets executed multiple times, while called once

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm currently working on a school project, we have to make a game in c++ console Application. And I'm currently having some issues with the AI moving. So once the players moves the bot can make his move. But for some reason the function gets executed multiple times.

**The Function where the bot get his move (monsterMove):**

```
void playerMove() {
COORD playerCord = { playerX,playerY }; 
memset(map3, 0, sizeof(map3));
int c = 0;
switch ((c = _getch())) {
case KEY_UP:
    if (map[playerY-1][playerX] == ' ')
    {
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), playerCord);
        cout << " ";
        map[playerY][playerX] = ' ';
        playerY--;
    }
    break;
case KEY_DOWN:
    if (map[playerY + 1][playerX] == ' ')
    {
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), playerCord);
        cout << " ";
        map[playerY][playerX] = ' ';
        playerY++;
    }

    break;
case KEY_LEFT:
    if (map[playerY][playerX-1]== ' ')
    {
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), playerCord);
        cout << " ";
        map[playerY][playerX] = ' ';
        playerX--;
    }
    break;
case KEY_RIGHT:
    if (map[playerY][playerX + 1] == ' ')

    {
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), playerCord);
        cout << " ";
        map[playerY][playerX] = ' ';
        playerX++;
    }
    break;
default:
    break;
}
monsterMove(1);
map[playerY][playerX] = 157;
COORD playerCord2 = { playerX,playerY };

SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), playerCord2);
cout << "I";

playerMove();
}
```

**The function itself:**

```
void monsterMove(int moves) {
map[monsterY][monsterX] = ' ';
int row[] = { -1, 0, 0, 1 };
int col[] = { 0, -1, 1, 0 };
int toMove =BFS(map, playerX, playerY, monsterX, monsterY)-moves;

COORD monsterCoord2 = { monsterX,monsterY};
SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), monsterCoord2);
cout << ' ';
while (map3[monsterY][monsterX] != toMove)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
    {
        if ((map3[monsterY + col[k]][monsterX + row[k]] == map3[monsterY][monsterX] -1) && !( map3[monsterY][monsterX] == toMove))
        {
            monsterX = monsterX+ row[k];
            monsterY =monsterY+ col[k]; 
        }
    }
}
COORD monsterCoord = { monsterX,monsterY };
map[monsterY][monsterX] = 157;
SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), monsterCoord);
cout << 'M';
}
```

I've put breakpoints to see what exactly happens , and the line 'monsterMove();' gets executed multiple times. I really don't get what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: ***Off-topic*** (since *fix-my-code* request without any [MCVE]). Compile with all warnings and debug info: `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Improve the code to get no warnings. **Use the debugger `gdb`**, perhaps to run  step by step your program and understand what is going on.

Comment: Look at the last statement of `playerMove()`.   It is unconditionally calling itself recursively.   Which means everything else in code before that (including the call of `monsterMove()`) will be executed multiple times.

Comment: Yeah well that's the point, Once you take a move, the bot takes one too. But before you get a chance to take a second step, the bot takes 2, since it get's executed multiple times. Or am i missing something ?

Comment: Unconditional recursion is not the correct way to achieve your goal. Use some kind of loop instead of unconditional recursion.

Comment: How are you typing the input? I suspect there are some extra characters which are causing `_getch()` not to wait and calling your function multiple times without waiting between every up/down/left/right key presses?

Comment: Well thanks for the tips , I've changed it to a loop. But it keeps happening :/ 
Before using keys, I was working with 'W', 'A' , 'S' And 'D' keys , so you typed them in & press enter. and that worked fine. But since i started using the switch with the arrow keys it all stopped working correctly

Comment: I suggest that you add extra `if` so that `MonsterMove()` is only invoked when the character you get from `_getch()` is one of the four valid characters. Note this is a workaround and does not answer your original question.

Comment: To solve your original question you can set breakpoint on the switch line and examine the variables.

Comment: I propose an experiment, write a little code which only reads input like your program does and prints visible indicators for up, down, left, right, zero and "else". Using that program make sure that your input parsing acts as you expect. Make for example sure that pressing left does not cause one value zero and one value 'KEY_LEFT' being read. This by the way can also be used as a [mcve] for your question, if it does not itself directly give you the answer.

Answer (score 0):

An obvious issue with your code is that you are calling `playerMove()` inside `playerMove()`, and as I can see so far from the code you pasted there is nothing to stop the recursion. Also I don't find the line `MonsterMove();` mentioned by you at all in the code and even if such a line does exist, you are missing a argument and it won't even compile.

Comment: For the moment it's not supossed to stop. I'm still testing if the AI Works correctly , the parameter I give in the function,is the amount of moves the bot can make. That part works correctly , butI just don't get why he takes 2-3 steps before I'm able to give another input.

Comment: Clarify it in your question, not just comments.

Comment: Though unconditional recursion is bad and will likely cause problem in future, this is clearly not the answer to OP's question. And `monsterMove` is called after the `switch` statement with correct argument type. You probably missed that line.

Comment: The OP stated `MonsterMove();` So I literally checked for that. And I'm not going to argue with you whether doing this literal check is appropriate or not, or should I guess what the OP means.